# Children of components to do not get rendered

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to render an array of data grouped by *level*.
Typically, the data look like:

```js
let education: [
        { id: 1, level: "phD", institution: "University A", country: "USA" },
        { id: 2, level: "MSc", institution: "University B", country: "Switzerland" },
        { id: 3, level: "MSc", institution: "University C", country: "Switzerland" },
      ]
```

The main looks as follow:

```js
import React from "react";
import EducationHeader from "./EducationHeader";
import EducationItem from "./EducationItem";

export default function Education({ education, educationUpdateFn }) {
  let listOfLevels = education.map((item) => item.level);
  // sort and remove duplicates
  listOfLevels = listOfLevels
    .sort()
    .filter((v, i) => listOfLevels.indexOf(v) === i);

  return (
    <div>
      {listOfLevels.map((level) => (
        <EducationHeader key={level} name={level}>
          {education
            .filter((item) => item.level === level)
            .map((item) => {
              return (
                <EducationItem
                  key={item.id}
                  institution={item.institution}
                  country={item.country}
                />
              );
            })}
        </EducationHeader>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

In turn, the EducationHeader is really simple:

```js
import React from "react";

export default function EducationHeader({ name }) {
  return <h2>{name}</h2>;
}
```

and the EducationItem is also simple:

```js
import React from "react";

export default function EducationItem({ institution, country }) {
  return (
    <div>
      {institution} - {country}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Unfortunately, the EducationItem components do not get rendered.

I feel like I'm doing a very basic mistake in the EducationHeader rendering (such as a placeholder to render the children), but I can't pinpoint it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything between the `EducationHeader` component's opening and closing tag will be passed to the `EducationHeader` component as a `children` property on the `props` object.

So to render the `EducationItem` components, you need to render `props.children` in the `EducationHeader` component.

```
function EducationHeader({ name, children }) {
  return (
    <div>
     <h2>{name}</h2>
     { children }
    </div>
  );
}
```

For details, see: [`React - props.children`](https://reactjs.org/docs/glossary.html#propschildren)

Answer (score 0):

You're right, this is quite simple. You just need to tell your `<EducationHeader />` component to actually render its children. Perhaps something like this:

```
export default function EducationHeader({ name, children }) {
  return (
    <>
      <h2>{name}</h2>
      <div>{children}</div>
    </>
  );
}
```

The children of the header will be rendered wherever you place `{children}` in the component.